# Returning custom HTTP error reasons in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Google's own REST APIs return detailed response in case of an error, e.g:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalidBookshelfId",
"message": "Invalid bookshelf ID."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid bookshelf ID."
 }
}
```

In Google Cloud Endpoints for Python, it's possible to e.g. `raise endpoints.BadRequestException('Error message')`, but in addition to the error message I would like to return "code" or "reason" as in example above. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The code corresponds to the status code associated with `BadRequestException`. The other exceptions are [documented](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/exceptions) as well, for example `endpoints.UnauthorizedException` corresponds to the status code `401`. As for the `reason` and the `domain`, those are set by Google's API Infrastructure.

What did you have in mind that isn't possible to set in `message`?

Comment: There might be different error conditions associated with the same HTTP status code. If the the API client wants to act differently upon these error conditions, how can we differentiate between them? Certainly the client may parse the message, but it feels like a hack. It would be better to have separate fields for message and error code/reason.

Comment: The problem is that message requires manual string parsing on the side of the client, either forcing him to create exceptions on his end then handling, or parsing strings at the API level.