# How to define a user defined MessageField like DateTimeField using ProtoRPC?

Tags: android, python, google-cloud-endpoints, protorpc

I would like to create a user defined MessageField like DateTimeField. I have created one as follows:

```
class ErrorMessage(Message):
    code = StringField(1, required=True)
    message = StringField(2, required=True)
    reference = StringField(3, required=True)

class ErrorField(MessageField):
    message_type = ErrorMessage

    @util.positional(3)
    def __init__(self, number, **kwargs):
        super(ErrorField, self).__init__(self.message_type, number, **kwargs)
```

Does it sound right? I have used this ErrorField  as one of the field in response class of Google cloud endpoints. It works well with JS client but when used with android, error object  gets in the format error="".

```
     return  MyResponse(
        isSaved=False,
        error=ErrorMessage(code="200", message=simplejson.dumps(form.errors), reference="form validation error")
       )

     from protorpc.messages import Message, StringField, MessageField

     class MyResponse(Message):
        isSaved = StringField(1, required=True)
        error = ErrorField(2, required = False)
```

I need common Error class for my endpoints, for that I need a custom ErrorField. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need this for Cloud Endpoints? Have you heard about custom error codes?

Comment: @bossylobster This was for helping the client side developer to understand what is the actual error. code -> Something to easily identify the error. So that they can use the code to display custom message
message -> A human readable/presentable error message, so that people can display it to end-user
reference -> Something we as developers can do to debug, i.e a string we put in logs, so that we can search the logs for the particular occurrence of the error

Comment: Sorry, I haven't heard about custom error codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Endpoints Exceptions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/exceptions) documentation.

For example, to send a `400`

```
raise endpoints.BadRequestException('A bad thing happened.')
```

Some more helpful answers:

[Returning custom HTTP error reasons in Google Cloud Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706271)

[How can one subclass endpoints.ServiceException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399254)